# Make ghostscript run from Windows command line natively

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, python, ghostscript

My problem: I am using Python to print plots which I usually output as .pdf file. Now I want to use .eps files, but Ghostscript is required (which I noticed because my Python console gave the error "Command gs not found").

Now I installed Ghostscript and I even went so far as to write an AutoRun into the registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> Software -> Microsoft -> CommandProcessor` with the value set to a .cmd file where I define an alias `doskey gs=gswin64c` (since on Windows the executable is named `gswin64c` but Python wants to run the Linux version `gs`).

Anyway, I still get the error. The bottom of the Python console prints:
`gs_distill your image.\nHere is the full report generated by ghostscript:\n\n' + fh.read())
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly`.

I believe the error is connected to Python not being able to run Ghostscript, but don't know where to go from here. Any solutions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try add the python _offending command_ you used? Give it a look [here too](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19745282/3569208)and maybe even more [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27354105/3569208). Ps Welcome on SuperUser

Comment: The offending line was `plt.savefig(r'{}.eps'.format(filename), format="eps", dpi=1000)`. Anyhow, I kinda solved my problem by... well, rebooting. Seems like either Ghostscript or the registry edit needed a reboot to properly function.

Comment: _"accept yourself"_ ... when you can. `:)`. Good.

Comment: In another 2 days! :D Thanks for the help, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is awkward. Rebooting solved my problem. It seems like I did the right steps, but without reboot it wouldn't work. Maybe this can be of help for someone else in the future.

Comment: To reboot the computer is not always needed, can be enough to restart any explorer instance, [but often helps](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/windows-registry-changes-is-a-restart-always/e131b560-1d03-4b12-a32c-50df2bf12752?msgId=9fdf4200-b6d9-43b5-8e40-f5b3f098ee74).